# Unsubscribe link being pulled from a DE is not working

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, dataextensions

I have a DE with multiple languages and in the unsubscribe field within the DE I have:

`Wenn du diese E-Mails nicht mehr bekommen möchtest, kannst du dich hier von dem Newsletter <a href="%%unsub_center_url%%" style="color: #666666; text-decoration: underline;">abmelden</a>.`

There are many variations of this in different languages.

When I test the mail my link comes out as:

https://user-content.s6.sfmc-content.com/%%unsub_center_url%%

Can anyone help?

Comment: Sorry just to add I am using a look up to pull in the data, everything is working apart from the <a> info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume the entire text above is stored within an ampscript vatriable - let's say: `@footer`.

You will need to utilise [TreatAsContent](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/treatascontent.htm) function, to force Marketing Cloud to process the ampscript helt within this variable.
So instead of printing:

```
%%=v(@footer)=%%
```

You should wrap it in treatascontent:

```
%%=treatascontent(@footer)=%%
```

Comment: thank-you thank-you!!! that worked a treat, you learn something new everyday.

Comment: You are welcome @Factor33 - remember to mark the answer as accepted, for the benefit of the community, as [described in this article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).